# Distance of every possible path between all nodes in minimum spanning tree

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree

I want to get distance of all nodes from all nodes. There are a few questions regarding this but none solves my problem.
What my appoach is that I am implementing recursive DFS and storing the result of each path while backtracking but the problem is I am having high running time and I a going through a path N number of times (N being the number of edges).

As you can see in my code I am running dfs for every possible node as a root. I dont know how to reuse the path to know the answer just in One Iteration of DFS search.

I think it could be done in O(n) as its a minimum spanning tree and there is only one path between a pair of nodes.

my code :

```
vector<int> visited(50001);
map< pair<ll,ll> , ll> mymap;
map<ll, vector<ll> > graph;

void calc(ll start,ll node)
{
    visited[node]=1;
    vector<ll>::iterator it;
    for (it = graph[node].begin(); it != graph[node].end(); ++it)
    {
        if (!visited[*it])
        {
            ans+=mymap[make_pair(node,*it)];
            mymap[make_pair(start,*it)]=ans;
            calc(start, *it);
            ans-=mymap[make_pair(node,*it)];
        }
    }
}
```

In main :

```
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        fill(visited.begin(),visited.end(),0);
        ans=0;
        calc(i,i);
    }
```

Comment: Why are you trying to reinvent algorithms? How are repeated applications of Dijkstra or Floyd-Warshall, which were suggested as solutions to your previous questions, insufficient for your needs? There's a reason nobody uses DFS to solve the All-Pairs Shortest Path problem.

Comment: They are working but as said they are taking too much running time for higher value of N thats why I went to DFS. which has reduced the running time a bit but going through same edge N number of times can be reduced I think but I dont know how to proceed.

Comment: If those algorithms are taking too much time, you'll have to look for something in the graph structure that can reduces the search space. As mentioned before, if you have an admissible heuristic, you can use A*. If not, well, big graphs take a long time. Your current approach is not feasible as the minimum spanning tree is not guaranteed to contain the edges of the shortest path between two given nodes.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a solution of complexity **O(n * logn)** using divide and conquer. Let me share it.

Let's choose an edge **e** of distance **d** which is connecting node **a** and **b**. Let's cut it. Now we have two tree with root **a** and **b**. Let's assume,

- number of nodes in tree **a** = na
- sum of distance between every node in tree **a** is = ca
- sum of distance of every node to root in tree **a** is = ra
- number of nodes in tree **b** = nb
- sum of distance between every node in tree **b** is = cb
- sum of distance of every node to root in tree **b** is = rb

So the distance between every node in the original tree is:
 ca + cb + (nb * ra + na * d * nb + na * rb))

Now, we can calculate the sum of distance of every node in tree **a** or **b** using same approach. One thing to be careful is that, we have to choose such edge **e** such that the difference between the number of components isn't much. You can always find an edge in a tree that if you cut that edge, the difference between the number of nodes in resulting two trees won't be more than 1.